# "** exception error: undefined function add:addfunc/0 in Erlang "

Tags: erlang, erlide

I'm trying to execute a simple erlang program of adding two numbers.
I'm trying to do this in Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

When i execute this program, I'm getting the error as shown below:

```
** exception error: undefined function add:addfunc/0
```

How do i go about solving this error? Thanks in advance.

This program when executed in the erlang shell is working fine. But when it comes to eclipse it's giving me this error. Not this, any program for that matter is giving me the similar error. Guess I would be missing something about the eclipse configuration.

EDIT:

Anyways, This is the sample add program,

```
-module(add). 
-export([addfunc/0]).

addfunc() -> 
    5 + 6.
```

Comment: Please share your code in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

This message tells you that module `add` doesn't have an exported function `addfunc/0`.
Ensure the function you want to be called has exactly that name, doesn't expect any
parameters, is
exported, the module is
compiled, the search path includes the compiled beam file and that there is no module clashes using `code:clash()`

Update

It's not clear how erlide (eclipse erlang plug-in you seem to use) compiles and runs a program. Try to compile source using erlc or inside erl shell. That way you'll have much easier controllable environment and you'll better understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same problem -for a tail recursive fibonacci function- below:

```
-module(math2).
-export([fibonacci/1]).

fibonacci(0) -> 0;
fibonacci(1) -> 1;
fibonacci(M) -> fibonacci(M-1) + fibonacci(M-2).
```

In the end, had realized that this is a compile-time exception. Then, have opened a new tab on my shell and tried with erlc, instead of erl.

```
$ erlc math2.erl
```

Now I am also able to see math2.beam file created.
Called fibonacci with 10:

```
4> math2:fibonacci(10).
55
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not compiled the code and you are trying to run the program.

In eclipse, using the "Run" icon, trigger the run; which will get you to the erl shell in the console window.
There you do -

```
cd("C:\Learning_ERL\src").
```

And you should see output like-

```
(Learning-ERL@DALAKSHM-MNFSM)7> cd("C:\Learning_ERL\src").
c:/Learning_ERL/src
ok
```

Then compile the code -

```
c(add)
```

you should see something like this on the erl shell-

```
(Learning-ERL@DALAKSHM-MNFSM)10> c(add).
{ok,add}
```

Now you should be seeing a new file called - add.beam in the same directory as that of your erl source file - add.erl

> add.beam is a bytecode file

**Now you should be able to run the program without any error**

Answer (score -1):

How do you try to execute your code?

In your editor, right-click and choose "Run as"->"Erlang application". The VM that is launched will have your project loaded automatically and when editing/saving a file it will get reloaded. When launching, a console appears and you can call your code from there.

If it still doesn't work, what message do you get for `m(add).`?